# How to retrieve HTML representation of components?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to output `HTML` codes of my `vaadin`'s components at my `console`. I didn't find any methods for this . Can it be possible ?

Comment: Now I am using vaadin 7.2.4

Comment: I think its not possible since vaadin only works on server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve component's generated HTML with Vaadin's server-side programming mode.

If you really need to do it, you could write your own extension what transfers component's generated HTML from browser to server after it's rendered. Writing your extension means the you need to it with GWT (GWT Web Toolkit, formerly Google Web Toolkit).

Comment: I found a way to step by step from [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html)